# error Symdony2 with hwiOAuthBundle: you have requested a non existing service

Tags: facebook, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I'm working in a project in `Symfony2` and i need to use `facebook` users to login in my application so i installed `HwiOAuthBundle` and when i run my app i get this error: `You have requested a non-existent service "hwi_oauth.account.connector"`

this is my configuration for the bundle:

**config.yml:**

```
hwi_oauth:
  firewall_name: main_hwi
  http_client:
      verify_peer: false
  connect: 
      confirmation: true

  resource_owners:
    facebook:
      type: facebook
      client_id: "%oauth.facebook.id%"
      client_secret: "%oauth.facebook.secret%"
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        OC\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_AUTEUR, ROLE_MODERATEUR]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:        
        hwi:
            id: oc.oauth.user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false                         

        main_hwi:
            context: user
            pattern: /.*
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: /login/check-facebook
                login_path: /connect
                failure_path: /connect
                oauth_user_provider: 
                    service: oc.oauth.user_provider
            logout: true
            anonymous: true      

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

**routing.yml**

```
hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /login

facebook_login: 
    pattern: /login/check-facebook   


oc_platform:
    resource: "@OCPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /platform
```

**UserProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\OAuth;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider as BaseOAuthUserProvider;

class UserProvider extends BaseOAuthUserProvider {          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found  2 useful tutorials that solve this problem. here are the links

[Symfony2 with HwiOAuthBundle Without FOSUserBundle](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/symfony-hwioauthbundle-and-google-sign-in/)

[Symfony2 with HwiOAuthBundle With FOSUserBundle](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697#file-security-yml-L11)